# Bootstrap-vue columns overlapping on smaller mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

We've been alerted to the fact that our layout is causing overlaps on certain mobile devices. This is the part of the grid that's causing problems:

```
<FluidContainer>
    <BRow>
        <BCol cols="8" lg="4">
            <div class="float-left d-flex m-10">
                <router-link to="/" class="text-decoration-none">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <!-- this is an image -->
                        <Logo class="d-inline-block align-top m-20" />
                        <!-- this is some text -->
                        <Strapline class="d-inline-block" /> 
                    </div>
                </router-link>
            </div>
        </BCol>
        <BCol cols="4" lg="8" class="d-flex">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-100 justify-content-end">
                <BRow class="w-100">
                <NavBarToggle
                    v-if="displayMobileNavigationToggle"
                    :navbarCollapseId="navbarCollapseId"
                    v-on:click.native="navbarToggleClicked"
                    class="d-md-block d-lg-none"
                />
                </BRow>
            </div>
        </BCol>
    </BRow>
</FluidContainer>
```

What happens is that regardless of the value of "cols" in the two BCol containers, the first col with the image and text takes up a minimum width and the navigation element overlaps it. There is space on the left-hand side of the screen to shift things left and potentially make room, but the layout doesn't use it.

[image]

Is there a way to either shift things left, or potentially truncate the text to fix this? Or is it a problem we just have to live with?

Comment: Try using negative value for margin.

Answer (score 2):

Using flex box create two section, one for text and one for nav icon. Also decrease the font size of your text and use negative value for margin to seperate them.

Comment: I will have a play with this suggestion, but the immediate impact is that it screws up the full version of the site, leading to a big space between the logo and the text